# Does payable macro change the function parameters?

Tags: nearprotocol

in rust, `nft_mint()` declaration

```
#[payable]
pub fn nft_mint(&mut self, token_id: TokenId, receiver_id: AccountId) -> Self {
  // ...
}
```

using the `nft_mint()` method in javascript

```
await contract.nft_mint({}, GAS_AMOUNT, ATTACHED_DEPOSIT);
```

I see that `nft_mint` in javascript has three arguments which are different from the `rust` code.
Is it because of that `payable` macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contract function arguments are passed in the first argument (object) on JS side, so it should be:

```
await contract.nft_mint({ token_id: "my_kitten", receiver_id: "frol.near" }, GAS_AMOUNT, ATTACHED_DEPOSIT);
```

“payable” attribute just adds a single assert at the beginning of the function body that checks that the attached deposit is non-zero. It does not alter  the function arguments.